# Need to modify kernel module loading

Tags: usb, wireless, software-installation, kernel

I have a Rosewill RNX-N180UBE (with Realtek RTL8191SU chipset) that I want to work with Raspbian Wheezy (Raspberry Pi).  Right now "lsmod" shows that the wifi driver being loaded is "r8712u", and apparently what I need is the "r8192cu" module. (based on this thread: http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?pid=17460)

I'd like to stop having the wrong module loaded, and get the right one to load, but I need some specific instructions on how to do it.  I am not sure that the "r8192cu" module exists on my SD card.

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

To stop having wrong module loaded you have to put your module name at /etc/modprobe.d/ as a conf file.

Create a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d folder with module you want to put in blacklist.

```
echo "blacklist r8712u" >> /etc/modprobe.d/r8712u.conf
```

To load r8192cu module run command below.

```
modprobe r8192cu
```

If you have error like '**FATAL: Module r8192cu not found.**' that means you haven't r8192cu module installed. You have to install it first. Please look at that document : http://blog.kartolo.de/2012/07/20/installing-wifi-adapter-on-raspberry-pi/